# Adding space to each array output

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a space after each output but its only appearing on the last output

```
if ($en['mm_wmeet']) {
    $tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_wmeet']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
        $en['mm_wmeet'] = $tmp[$i]. "&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning, not adding. Use `.=` to add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best method is str_replace()

```
$en['mm_wmeet'] = str_replace(',', '&nbsp;', $en['mm_wmeet']);
```

Answer (score 6):

As Pekka said, use either `.=`:

```
$tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_wmeet']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
    $en['mm_wmeet'] .= $tmp[$i] . "&nbsp;";
}
```

Or alternatively, use `implode`:

```
$tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_wmeet']);
$en['mm_wmeet'] = implode("&nbsp;", $tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The net effect of what you're doing is to just replace the commas with spaces, so you can use PHP's built-in `str_replace` function:

```
$en['mm_wmeet'] = str_replace(',', '&nbsp;', $en['mm_wmeet']);
```

If your search string was more complicated, you could use a regular expression instead.

For example if you wanted to also strip out any existing plain white space between the list items, you could use this:

```
$en['mm_wmeet'] = preg_replace('/,\s*/', '&nbsp;', $en['mm_wmeet']);
```

If you really want an additional trailing space after that, just append it.